Problema al manejar htmlFor y id con props en React
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/books/genres.css';
import { FaCheck } from 'react-icons/fa';

interface GenreProps {
    text: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    genre: string;
    onClick: () => void;
}

export const Genres: React.FC<GenreProps> = ({
    text,
    isActive = false,
    genre,
    onClick,
}) => {

    return (
        <div
            className={`check-container ${isActive ? 'active-filter' : ''}`}
            onClick={onClick}
        >
            <input type='checkbox' id={genre} checked={isActive} />
            <label htmlFor={genre} >
                {isActive ? <FaCheck className='checked' /> : null}
                {text}
            </label>
        </div>
    );
};


Estoy trabajando en un componente React llamado Genres que muestra un checkbox y un label asociado. Cuando paso htmlFor al label y id al checkbox directamente en texto plano, todo funciona como espero. Sin embargo, cuando intento pasar estos valores como props (genre para htmlFor y id para checkbox), el clic en el label ya no activa el checkbox.

Tanto para la prop id en input como la prop htmlFor en label usas solo el valor de genre, ¿eso esta bien?, debes agregar el componente padre para ver como esta la lógica de onClick e isActive, agrega el ejemplo minimo del componente padre.
